# Using DrawerLayout with BottomSheetBehavior

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I have a problem when opening DrawerLayout while having BottomSheetBehavior at the bottom of the layout. BottomSheetBehavior layout is hidden at the moment, but the DrawerLayout is cropped at a place where is BottomSheetBehavior layout top height.

Any ideas?

[DrawerLayout with BottomSheetBehavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCJ17.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/root"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <com.some.example.widgets.SearchBarWidget
                android:id="@+id/searchBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.some.example.MapView
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

layout_bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/gestureLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/expandCollapseImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/expand"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Without seeing your code or layout xml, answering this would be guessing.  Show your stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged layout like that, I put ConstraintLayout outside CoordinatorLayout and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.some.example.widgets.SearchBarWidget
            android:id="@+id/searchBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.some.example.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_sheet" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```